# Spring Boot CORS not letting react app in localhost port 3000 to acces content

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot

I am learning spring boot from a youtube course, we are doing a rest api and consuming the backend data from react client, i am not using spring security so as the video said i just have to configure the @CrossOrigin annotation as follows in the RestController:

**Controller that blocks request from react client**

```
package com.user.springBackend.controller;


import com.user.springBackend.model.Employee;
import com.user.springBackend.repository.EmployeeRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    //get all employees

    @GetMapping("/employees")
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees(){
        return employeeRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

the react client is doing the request with axios as seen here:

**React client code doing request**

```
import axios from 'axios';
const EMPLOYEE_API_BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/api/V1/employees';

class EmployeeService{

    getEmployees(){
        return axios.get(EMPLOYEE_API_BASE_URL);
    }

}

export default new EmployeeService();
```

and the error that the browser sends when i run both applications is:

[image: cors error when running both applications]

How can i fix this? there are other question that may tend to see this as a duplicated question but the others are using spring security which change the configuration needed to cors.

also my pom.xml file is this:

**pom.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.tito</groupId>
    <artifactId>springBackend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springBackend</name>
    <description>backend in springboot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>18</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: If you are hitting port 8080 on the server why are you enabeling port 3000 for CORS?

Comment: because the request comes from the client that is running on port 3000, or what do you mean?

Comment: It doesn't matter where the client runs, the problem here is about the browser running XHR requests to the server. With CORS you let the browser do the request, so what matters is the url and port the browser is targeting on your server.

Comment: Could you please explain that a little bit deeper please, also the tutorial configured CORS in port 3000 and there it runs well, also I just changed the annotation to http://localhost:8080 and didn't run.

Comment: To get around CORS you need to understand what it does and how it works. I suggest you checkout this documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: thanks, just read and is what i knew about CORS, the client make a request and send in headers the origin from where he is doing the request i.e where is running (?) the server must have in it access control allow origin policy the http://localhost:3000 url, also saw the request in the browser and server in response does not have the access control allow origin header, so maybe i think is spring missconfiguration the problem

Comment: `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")`
Try changing it to this. Make sure you restart the Spring Boot App

Comment: @heyitsvajid, doesn't @CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*") allow access to your app backend by all external domains?